# c# deserialize json array and data binding

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8, json.net

I have trouble to deserialize this json file. I want to bind the "favoriteSongs" array to my view in xaml and display all the informations in a longlistselector.

```
{
    "_id": "56fd864ff28510694a6a7b5e",  
    "addFavorites": {
          "favoriteSongs": [
                   {
                           "_id": "570aeb89869a0520e0d0365c",
                           "title": "get lucky",
                           "album": "random access memory",
                           "primaryArtist": "daft punk",
                           "artist": "570ae933cd7d1072b430ea51",
                           "primaryGenre": "electro",
                           "genre": "570ae933cd7d1072b430ea52",
                           "duration": "3m31s",
                           "year": 2013
                   },
                   { ... }
          ]
}
```

In my view model im using an observablecollection to add the informations from the json, here the "getFavoriteSongsModel" is my RootObject

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
          getFavoriteSongsModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetFavoriteSongsModel>(e.Result);
          getFavoriteSongs.Add(new GetFavoriteSongsModel()
            {
                Id = getFavoriteSongsModel.Id,
                Favorites = getFavoriteSongsModel.Favorites
            });
```

I tried to use this pattern with another observablecollection that points to a class with a list of all the infomations i need but it crashes everytime. I don't know how to use the "Favorites" variable, i know it is populated but i can't display what i want in the xaml.

```
            <Grid>
                <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding getFavoriteSongs}">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FavoriteSongs.Album}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FavoriteSongs.Title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create a sample Code on base of my understanding.

I have Created three classes on based of Json string from [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), which is very useful to create classes on based of Json string.

Three classes are as following

```
 public class FavoriteSong
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string album { get; set; }
    public string primaryArtist { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string primaryGenre { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}

public class AddFavorites
{
    public ObservableCollection<FavoriteSong> favoriteSongs { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public AddFavorites addFavorites { get; set; }
}
```

I have just use your string as json and on base I have create this samle.

Following code will deserialize json string

```
   public MainClass objMainClass { get; set; }
  string strJson = "{\"_id\": \"56fd864ff28510694a6a7b5e\",\"addFavorites\": {\"favoriteSongs\": [{\"_id\": \"570aeb89869a0520e0d0365c\",\"title\": \"get lucky\",\"album\": \"random access memory\",\"primaryArtist\": \"daft punk\",\"artist\": \"570ae933cd7d1072b430ea51\",\"primaryGenre\": \"electro\",\"genre\": \"570ae933cd7d1072b430ea52\",\"duration\": \"3m31s\",\"year\": 2013}]}}";

        objMainClass = new MainClass();
        objMainClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(strJson);

        MainLongListSelector.DataContext = objMainClass.addFavorites;
```

and binding in XAML is as following

```
<phone:LongListSelector
        x:Name="MainLongListSelector"
        Margin="0,0,-12,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding favoriteSongs}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    Margin="0,0,0,17">
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding album}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding title}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Hope so it will be helpful to you.